# How can I pass multiple params in Jekyll with Liquid?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have [found a Ruby](https://gist.github.com/patrickfav/3f9127e25dd6538f0d682b89cbfaefd9) plugin for Jekyll to obfuscate an email address like this in a Jekyll webpage with Liquid

```
{{ site.email | mailObfuscate }}
```

However, I would like to pass multiple params to `mailObfuscate`

I have tried the following

```
{{ email=site.email, linkText='foo bar' | mailObfuscate }}
```

However, this gives an error when building my site

> Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 89): Unexpected character = in "{{ email=site.email, linkText='foo bar' | mailObfuscate }}" in privacy.html
>   Liquid Exception: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass in privacy.html
>   Error: undefined method`gsub' for nil:NilClass
>   Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.

Running the trace gives the following error

> 1: from D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/common.rb:103:in `escape'
>   D:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb:305:in`escape':
>   undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

The complete trace can be found at [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KiNnwchu)

How can I pass multiple variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the method to take a 2nd argument, then you can use it as the link text. Try this:

```
require "base64"
require "uri"

module ObfuscateMailAddress
  def mailObfuscate(email_address, link_text )
    base64Mail = Base64.strict_encode64(URI::encode(email_address))

    # See http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/
    output = "<a href=\"#\" "
    output += "data-contact=\"#{base64Mail}\" target=\"_blank\" "
    output += "onfocus=\"this.href = 'mailto:' + atob(this.dataset.contact)\">"
    output += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write(atob(\"#{base64Mail}\"));</script>#{link_text}</a>"
    return output
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(ObfuscateMailAddress)
```

To pass multiple arguments in your liquid template, the syntax is a bit strange, [see documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers#advanced-output-filters).  The string on the left side of the pipe automatically get's passed as the first argument to your ruby method, while additional arguments get passed with a colon.

```
{{ 'test@example.com' | mailObfuscate:'myLinkText' }}
```

But you also, if you are on Ruby >= 2.3, you can make your method more readable with no need for all the escape characters and better syntax highlighting in your editor if you change your method to use SQUIGGLY HEREDOC for your string definition, explicit `return` is not required in anycase. For Ruby < 2.3 you can still use regular HEREDOC just replace `~` with `-` but you just have extra indentation in your string, which is no problem anyway for rendered html.

```
def mailObfuscate(email_address, link_text )
  base64Mail = Base64.strict_encode64(URI::encode(email_address))

  ouput = <<~HTML
  <a href="#" data-contact="#{base64Mail}" target="_blank" 
     onfocus="this.href = 'mailto:' + atob(this.dataset.contact)" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(atob("#{base64Mail}"));
    </script>
    #{link_text}
  </a>
  HTML
end
```

And when it is called like this:

```
 puts mailObfuscate('foo@bar.com', 'foobar')
```

It will render:

```
  <a href="#" data-contact="Zm9vQGJhci5jb20=" target="_blank"
     onfocus="this.href = 'mailto:' + atob(this.dataset.contact)" >
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write(atob("Zm9vQGJhci5jb20="));
    </script>
    foobar
  </a>
```

As a side note, [ruby style guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide) recommends we use `snake_case` for method names so you might wanna use `mail_obfuscate` for your method name instead.

Comment: Thanks for answering,

I've adapted my code with your modifications (not the Ruby>2.3 version). However, when building the Jekyll site I now get the following error

~~~
    Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 76): Expected end_of_string but
    found open_round in "{{ mailObfuscate(site.email,'foo bar') }}" in privacy.html
~~~

Any idea what this may be?

Comment: @JoostvanderDrift see updated answer with correct liquid format for multiple arguments, the syntax is strange but see docs for more info.

Comment: You can run this script to see that it works https://pastebin.com/6B1wL7y2

Comment: thank you very much. I now have it working, I have even add a Base64 encoding of the link_text itself!

```
    output += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write(atob(\"#{base64Text}\"));</script></a>"
```

Comment: @JoostvanderDrift yeah it was a little tricky but the docs helped me figure it out. I haven't worked much with liquid but I like it.  Also, you can comment code in comments with single backticks instead of triple.